# Altering of dataframe index upon appending

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

why does the indices of a dataframe change into tuple when appended with another dataframe in python?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 
'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 
'spoonbills'], 'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, 'nan', 6, 3, 5.5, 'nan', 8, 4], ' 
 visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2], 'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 
'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=[(labels)])
mylist={'birds' :'penguin', 'age':'3' , 'visits' : 22,'priority':'yes'}
newdf=pd.DataFrame(mylist,index=['k'])
df=df.append(newdf)
df
```

Comment: birds age visits priority
(a,) Cranes 3.5 2 yes
(b,) Cranes 4 4 yes
(c,) plovers 1.5 3 no
(d,) spoonbills nan 4 yes
(e,) spoonbills 6 3 no
(f,) Cranes 3 4 no
(g,) plovers 5.5 2 no
(h,) Cranes nan 2 yes
(i,) spoonbills 8 3 no
(j,) spoonbills 4 2 no
k penguin 3 22 yes

Comment: my indices have become(a,) and so on instead of merely the alphabets. What is the reason and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen multi index to dataframe as tuples while creating dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=[(labels)])

df.index
```

MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

If your requirement is not to have multi indexed tuple index, you can switch it off by assigning the list of indexes directly

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'birds': ['Cranes', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills', 'Cranes', 'plovers', 'Cranes', 'spoonbills', 'spoonbills'], 
        'age': [3.5, 4, 1.5, 'nan', 6, 3, 5.5, 'nan', 8, 4], 
        'visits': [2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2], 
        'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}

labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=labels)
mylist={'birds' :'penguin', 'age':'3' , 'visits' : 22,'priority':'yes'}
newdf=pd.DataFrame(mylist,index=['k'])
df.append(newdf)
```

Out:

```
    age birds   priority    visits
a   3.5 Cranes  yes 2
b   4   Cranes  yes 4
c   1.5 plovers no  3
d   nan spoonbills  yes 4
e   6   spoonbills  no  3
f   3   Cranes  no  4
g   5.5 plovers no  2
h   nan Cranes  yes 2
i   8   spoonbills  no  3
j   4   spoonbills  no  2
k   3   penguin yes 22
```